# How to get the total duration of a video using MediaElement of UWP

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, mediaelement

I'am playing a video using  MediaElement. Now I want to get it's total duration before playing it. How is it possible?

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
foreach (string extension in FileExtensions.Video)
{
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(extension);
}
StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
// mediaPlayer is a MediaElement defined in XAML
if (file != null)
{
    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
    videoMediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);

    var totalDurationTime = videoMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;//get value zero
    var totalDurationTime1 = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(videoMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds);//get zero
    videoMediaElement.Play();
}
```

Comment: maybe you need to wait for the MediaOpened event and then check the length after the file has been loaded. According to the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_MediaElement_MediaOpened) at least for a live stream a value other then 0 is set, so i assume in case of a local file its length should be set as well after that event

Answer (score 4):

As @Hannes said, if you want to get the media duration by `NaturalDuration` property of [`MediaElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement) class, you need to put the above code snippet inside [`MediaOpened`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_MediaElement_MediaOpened) event handle, for example:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="videoMediaElement" MediaOpened="videoMediaElement_MediaOpened"></MediaElement>

private void videoMediaElement_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var totalDurationTime = videoMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds; 
    var totalDurationTime1 = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(videoMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds);
}
```

Actually, you can get the duration of the video file through the file [`VideoProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileproperties.videoproperties). You can get the duration even before you opened the file.

```
StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
Windows.Storage.FileProperties.VideoProperties videoProperties = await file.Properties.GetVideoPropertiesAsync();
Duration videoDuration = videoProperties.Duration;
```

Answer (score 0):

in xaml  use

```
<TextBox x:Name="startTime" Width="20" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="1" InputScope="Number" />
```

and

```
<TextBox x:Name="endTime" Width="20" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,630,135" BorderThickness="1" InputScope="Number"/>
```

then in xaml.cs file

```
long x = Int64.Parse(startTime.Text);
long y = Int64.Parse(endTime.Text);


var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(pickedFile);
clip.TrimTimeFromStart = new TimeSpan(x * 10000000);
clip.TrimTimeFromStart = new TimeSpan(y * 10000000);


composition = new MediaComposition();
composition.Clips.Add(clip);
mediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
 mediaStreamSource = composition.GeneratePreviewMediaStreamSource((int)mediaElement.ActualWidth, (int)mediaElement.ActualHeight);
mediaElement.SetMediaStreamSource(mediaStreamSource);
```

you wil get total duration by using the following code : `clip.OriginalDuration.TotalSeconds`